# UnknownHostException: Name or service not known with CAS

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, cas

I am trying to deploy a cas on a remote machine and I get the following error:

> [org.jasig.cas.util.http.SimpleHttpClientFactoryBean] - fooHostName:
>   fooHostName: Name or service not known java.net.UnknownHostException:
>   fooHostName: fooHostName: Name or service not known   at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1473)  at
>   org.jasig.cas.util.http.SimpleHttpClientFactoryBean.buildHttpClient(SimpleHttpClientFactoryBean.java:202)
>     at
>   org.jasig.cas.util.http.SimpleHttpClientFactoryBean.getObject(SimpleHttpClientFactoryBean.java:164)
>     at
>   org.jasig.cas.util.http.SimpleHttpClientFactoryBean.getObject(SimpleHttpClientFactoryBean.java:1)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168)
>     //....  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.net.UnknownHostException: fooHostName: Name or service not known
>     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)   at
>   java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)    at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
>     at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1469)     ... 115
>   more

I performed the problem-free deployment on the premises with a simple XAMPP (MySql and Tomcat). On my remote machine I am also using a Tomcat 8.5.

What can be the reason for the error?

Comment: what hostname is configured in cas.properties?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: The hostname that you are using is correct? I don't think so. It try to solve "fooHostName" but it fails.  You can try to solve, from your remote server, the hostname with nslookup and you will see that it will fail.